# Why is the performance of my app not horrible when my uWSGI queue is full?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I get errors like this on a regular basis:

```
uWSGI listen queue of socket ":15109" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100)
```

But the app this is running on doesn't have ultra-fast requests. It has, say, 100ms requests. So, 100x100ms = 10 seconds. If there were a ton of requests sitting in a queue for 10 seconds, I would notice horrible performance on my app and see other alerts and metrics reflecting this. But I'm not seeing that. So is there some other phenomenon happening that causes this queue to fill up in a way that doesn't translate to requests actually being in a queue for that long? Do requests that are already served not get garbage collected?

Comment: From my understanding after browsing the source a bit, this is the number of connections in the queue on a listening socket. But the OS interfaces used to get this info seem to be super obscure (i.e. not really documented), so it could be that one of the counts is simply wrong. Also, do you have multiple sockets listening for connections?

Comment: I have multiple processes and the `listen` settings is for all of them, I learned. So my math wasn't quite right, it's actually 100x100ms / 7 = 1.4. Which I guess is the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the `listen` setting covers all processes. My app has 7, so my math should be 100x100ms / 7 = 1.4 seconds, which makes much more sense.

Comment: Cool. Nice to know the warning is actually working perfectly!